# Pressing submit gives fail PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a code

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "*******", "sitedb");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "MySQLi Connection was not established: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
$sel_user = "select * from members where username='$user' AND password='$pass'";
$run_user = mysqli_query($con, $sel_user);
$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);

if ($check_user > 0)
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
    if (isset($_POST['forms']))
    {
        echo "test form";
    }

    echo "<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Menu</TITLE>
<BODY>
<CENTER>
Menu
<P>
<TABLE WIDTH = 400><TR><TD align = right>
<FORM method='POST'>
<INPUT name='forms' TYPE='submit' VALUE='Form edit' id='forms'>
</FORM>
<FORM action='/logout.php'>
<INPUT name='logout' TYPE='submit' VALUE='Exit'>
</FORM>
</TD></TR></TABLE></CENTER>
</BODY>
</HTML>";
}
else
{
    echo "Failed. Wrong username or password.</br>";
}

?>
```

Every thing works well except one thing. When you press Form Edit button you get message "Failed. Wrong username or password."
I need it to display "test form" (line 16)

Comment: Do a conditional on the query execution and check for errors. Also passwords should be hashed.

Comment: Where is input field for username and password??

Comment: Input is in html file, i dont think that i should write them here because login system works well. This page can only be accessed by authorised users.

Comment: Why 2 form tags in same page ? You can use a single form as well. Because of this you are getting error. You need to check on which click your function should work. `if(isset($_POST['forms'])) OR if(isset($_POST['logout']))`

Comment: nope doesnt work for me

Comment: When developing and testing code, it is essential to have display_errors turned on. You've explicitly turned it off - do that in production but never testing.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: oops, my mistake :) well now it showes 
Notice: Undefined index: username in /var/www/html/login.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: password in /var/www/html/login.php on line 17

Comment: @Zajev: Your page *expects* the username/password to be in the `$_POST` array.  When you click `Form edit`, you're posting to this page, but it can't find the username/password.  You need to check if `$_SESSION['username']` exists, and if it does then don't try to run the query.

Comment: Page has username and password in $_POST while using                 $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);    but when it comes to if (isset($_POST['forms'])) he does not see it